# Get the Access control list for single folder from multiple servers

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm executing the script for getting the Access control list for single folder from multiple servers. while executing the script I've received the access list as `System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection`.

```
$a = @()
$servers = Get-Content "F:\Team CDS\ExchServerlist.txt"
ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
$b = New-Object System.Object
$b = get-acl "\\$server\F$\Team CDS" | select-object -property @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = { ($_.PSPath -split '::')[1]; } },owner,access
$a += $b
$a | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "F:\access1.csv"
}
```

Output :

```
\\9021\F$\Team CDS","OnlyL3","System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection"
\\9022\F$\Team CDS","OnlyL3","System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection"
\\9022\F$\Team CDS","OnlyL3","System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection"
```

Please help me to have access property updated on output file.

Comment: You can pipe the `Access` property to `Out-String` like this: `@{Label="Access";Expression={ $_.Access | Out-String }}` but the output will be a collection of objects. Essentially, you'll have a table inside your main table so for CSV export you'll need to do some additional formatting.

Comment: What information are you actually looking for? `Get-Acl` can return an object with many levels of access. That will not fit into a single line of output. You might need to use a foreach-Loop to cycle them all

Answer (score 0):

I usually expand the ACL out and just add the path and any other information I need from the security descriptor to each object:

```
Get-Content "F:\Team CDS\ExchServerlist.txt" | ForEach-Object {

    $Path = "\\$_\F$\Team CDS"

    $Acl = Get-Acl $Path
    $Acl | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | 
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $Path -PassThru  |
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value $Acl.Owner -PassThru

} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "F:\access1.csv"
```